# GRUB menu doesnt show while booting

Tags: bootloader

I had dual booted windows 8.1 and lubuntu. Recently i had refreshed windows 8.1 and since then i am unable to see Grub menu while i boot. However if i go to BIOS settings and then select the UBUNTU only then the GRub menu appears.

Comment: What do you mean "go to BIOS settings and then select the UBUNTU" do you have them separate drives?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two physical disks in your computer.

If you install a Windows over a Linux you overwirte the bootloader because Windows does not recognize any other OS. Only thing you can do is set the Linux HDD as default in your BIOS/EFI and use grub to boot Windows.

Or you could install grub4dos in your Windows and add your Linux partition to the menu. So it doesn't matter from which HDD you boot. Both bootloaders have both entries.